# Frequency-Domain Linear Regression MATLAB

Tags: regression, matlab, frequency

I am trying to implement this tutorial Frequency-Domain Linear Regression https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/frequency-domain-linear-regression.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com on my time series, but I don't understand part after first diagram, 3rdparagraph. There is sentence "Sampling the data monthly, the highest frequency in the spectral analysis is 1 cycle/2 months." How that can be highest frequence, isn`t it 1cycle/1month, because data are collected every month?

Comment: Questions here need to be self-contained. People aren't going to want to navigate elsewhere & read something to answer your question for you, & we want this thread to remain informative even if the link changes / goes dead. Can you make this self-contained? (Also, if you are just looking for help w/ how to use MATLAB, that would be off topic here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - when you submit time series data to a power spectrum analysis, the result you obtain looks like a histogram constructed via a line instead of vertical bars.  A power spectrum will have its greatest peak (spike) at the dominant cycle over the wavelength of the data submitted.  You can see this by adding together vertically several sine and cosine waves with various amplitudes and wavelengths.  If you use a large major cycle with a large amplitude, then that will be the dominant cycle which contributes to the sum, and there will be a spike in the power spectrum at the wavelength for the dominant cycle.   (be careful, you can perform power spectrum analyses based on wavelength or amplitude).